# How to call a Python function from an external JS file?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I was using some Javascript stuff for an uploader on a webpage, to test it I wrote it inline with the HTML (I know). I'm using Flask with Jinja2 templates so to connect my uploader(it just acts like a form) to the upload function in my Python, I just had

```
url: "{{url_for('upload_file')}}",
```

in the inline Javascript, because this could be referenced within the scope of the template. Now I've moved my JS to an external file and just included it in the HTML like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='uploader.js') }}">
  </script>
```

How can I call my Python function from the external js file? Is there some way of initializing it in the template and passing it in, or am I missing something really elementary here?

Edit: I ended up doing it a little different:

```
<script>
var link = "{{ url_for('upload_file') }}"
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='uploader.js') }}">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, you need to do this in the main file. Inside a script tag, you can define an object in the global scope, and set attributes to the results of your template calls. You can then refer to the object in your script file.

**Edit**

There's no special syntax: this is just standard Javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    template_vars = {
        url: "{{url_for('upload_file')}}",
        // etc
    }
</script>
```

and now your other script can access `template_vars.url` etc.

Comment: What is the syntax for this? Sorry, I'm a beginner at this type of thing. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. I did it a little differently, as you can see in my edit. Any advantage to doing it this way over the way I did?

Comment: Only if you have a lot of variables you want to pass from the template - it prevents polluting the global namespace with a whole load of extra names, by putting them inside a single one.